# Canonic form of A matrix defined by a condition of powers equation

Tags: matrices, geometry, minimal-polynomials

I have to solve this old exam problem:

A square matrix $A$ of order $4$ is not diagonalisable and satisfy this condition:

$(A−I)^4 = 4(A−I)^2 = 9(A−I)^2$

List all the possible canonic form of $A$, the characteristic polynomial and the minimal polynomial.

I already have the solution but I doesn't understand several part of it.
The first thig that my prof do to solve it is write this:

"By hypothesis we know that $A$ satisfies the following equations:

$(t−1)^2(t+1)(t−3)=0$

$(t−1)^2(t+2)(t−4)=0$"

First of all I don't get how he finds those equations.

Can you help me?

Comment: First, add to you post what it means, given the $4\times 4$ matrix A is not diagonalizable.  Second, try expanding $(A- I)^4$ and $4(A-I)^2$ and set those expansions equal to one another.

Comment: what do you know about the minimal polynomial? for example, of non-diagonalizable matrices?

Comment: Was $4(A−I)^2 = 9(A−I)^2$ a typo? (If that's what you really meant why not just say $(A-I)^2=0$?)

Comment: @Fabio if you know the answer and did not understand it, then try to ask what in the answer you did not get.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I suppose we could be in characteristic $5$.

Comment: @Fabio Possibly I suppose. Doesn't seem likely

Comment: @David C. Ullrich nope, it wasn't a typo.

Comment: Ok, then what sort of matrix is it? (Real entries?)

Comment: I suppose yes, it is not expressed in the exercise track

Comment: Look. There _are_ typos here! For example "the first thing the professor said" is _different_ in your comment and in the body of the question. The condition $(A−I)^4 = 4(A−I)^2 = 9(A−I)^2$ _can't_ be right, because that's exactly the same as saying $(A-I)^2=0$ - if that were right the professor would have said $A$ satisfied the equation $(t-1)^2=0$ instead of what you say he said. _read_ the quesion _carefully_, then **fix** it!

Comment: @David C. Ullrich I fixed the body of the question, when I tried to do this calc I obtained this: $4(A-I)^2=9(A-I)^2 -> 4A^2-8A-9A^2+18A=5I -> A^2-2A+I=0 -> A=I$, Maybe i'm wrong but i don't understand why it should be 0.

Comment: No, $A^2-2A+I=0$ does not imply that $A=I$! It implies exatly that $(A-I)^2=0$. Easier way to get there: Since $9(A-I)^2=4(A-I)^2$ it follows that $5(A-I)^2=0$. Divide by $5$.

Comment: I simply don't believe that the question was supposed to say $(A−I)^4 = 4(A−I)^2 = 9(A−I)^2$, because that's  such a stupid way of saying $(A-I)^2=0$ (and also then what you say the professor said makes no sense.) Look it up again. If that's how it really reads, ask the professor.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich Well, this is a screenshot of the original track https://gyazo.com/9746a1be7d54bb39b0e17ee94ea6b619 I did that exam too so i can confirm that the track isn't a prof's typo, also $(A−I)^2=0$ is actually a good point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days I successfully solved the problem:

First we have to breack the equivalence in two parts:

$(A-I)^4=4(A-I)^2$
and
$(A-I)^4=9(A-I)^2$

So we know that the first equation is represented by the polynomial:

$(t-1)^4-4(t-1)^2=(t-1)^2((t-1)^2-4)=(t-1)^2(t^2-2t-3)=(t-1)^2(t+1)(t-3)=0$

And the second:

$(t-1)^4-9(t-1)^2=(t-1)^2((t-1)^2-9)=(t-1)^2(t^2-2t-8)=(t-1)^2(t+2)(t-4)=0$

Now the minimal polynomial must be in this case in the form $(t+n)^k$ with $k>1$ because $A$ is not diagonalisable. So the minimal polynomial is:

$m\substack{A}(t)=(t-1)^2$

And the possible canonic form are:
$J\substack{1}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ or $J\substack{2}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

Now the only thing left is the characteristic polynomial that must be a 4th grade polynomial and because the only eigenvalues is $\lambda=1$ then

$p\substack{c}=(t-1)^4$.